# Chain upper() with contains() on a series

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes: `df1` and `df2`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
  
num = {'description': ['apple','Red APPLE is good',np.nan,'peach','melon',np.nan,'green apple'],
       'code': ['AA','AA','BB','BB','CC','BB','BB']} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(num) 

num2 = {'word': ['apple','peach'],
       'code': ['ZZ','YY']} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(num2)
```

If the `df1['description]` contains word `'apple'`, then the corresponding code should be `'ZZ'`. If it contains `'peach'`, then the corresponding code should be `'YY'`

Before comparing, I should convert first value to uppercase. How can I do that?
I tried to `chain.str.upper().contains(...)` but I got an error

```
for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
    df1['code'] = np.where(df1['description'].str.contains(df2['word'][i].upper()), df2['code'][i], df1['code'])
```

For each `NaN` from `df1['description']`, the code is changed to `'YY'` and this is not good. How can I avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass `case=False`:

```
df1.description.str.contains('apple', case=False)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2      NaN
3    False
4    False
5      NaN
6     True
Name: description, dtype: object
```

And to get the code:

```
pattern = '|'.join(df2.word)

df1['new_code'] = (df1.description.str.lower()
                      .str.extract(rf'\b({pattern})\b', expand=False)
                      .map(df2.set_index('word')['code'])
                  )
```

Output:

```
         description code new_code
0              apple   AA       ZZ
1  Red APPLE is good   AA       ZZ
2                NaN   BB      NaN
3              peach   BB       YY
4              melon   CC      NaN
5                NaN   BB      NaN
6        green apple   BB       ZZ
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

"case = False" do the trick and it doesn't matter if it's "Apple", "apple", "APPLE", etc

The second part it's a little bit complicated but somehow I think I managed to understand it.
For lines 0,1,3 and 6 the new code is correct but for lines with NaN , the new code should be "BB" and not NaN. Same for "melon": it should be "CC" instead of NaN.

I'm very new to pandas so I might get it wrong. Am I missing something?

Comment: Chain my code with `.fillna(df1['code'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I chained my code with `.fillna(df1['code'])` and it was perfect!

Of course, your code is more elegant, but starting from your explanation I modified my code as well and made it work after all :)

Practicaly, I replaced `NaN` with a string, performed the loop then replaced back the string with `NaN`
I also use `case = False` in `.str.contains` to capture "apple" written in any way.

```
df1['description'] = df1['description'].fillna('[temp_string]')

for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
    df1['code'] = np.where(df1['description'].str.contains(df2['word'][i], case = False), df2['code'][i], df1['code'])

df1['description'] = df1['description'].replace('[temp_string]', np.nan)
```

Thank you again.